# How to return a new String from a declarative macro?

Tags: string, rust, rust-macros, rust-decl-macros

So here I am, trucking along with Rustlings, until I get broadsided with test 4.

It wants me to write a macro that will satisfy the following code:

```
fn main() {
    if my_macro!("world!") != "Hello world!" {
        panic!("Oh no! Wrong output!");
    }
}
```

So, I wrote this:

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($val:expr) => {
        println!("Hello {}", $val);
    }
}
```

And Rustlings spat this out:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> exercises/test4.rs:15:31
   |
15 |     if my_macro!("world!") != "Hello world!" {
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found reference
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
              found type `&'static str`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

Which, you know. I get. I understand what the problem is, but I don't understand how to write a macro that will satisfy the code. I can change the code I'm testing against, but that's not what the test wants me to do. I'm only to write a macro. I'm stumped. I also don't understand how encapsulating the macro in a module is meant to help, but the test says it's a test on modules as well as macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`println!` will print to the `stdout`. Instead, you just want to format the string and return it from the macro. Use `format!` instead, and drop the `;` so that it will return the expression instead of `()`:

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($val:expr) => {
        format!("Hello {}", $val)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. The issue I was having was I couldn't figure out how to make it evaluate to "Hello world!" without creating new variables, which you can't do. Bravo Mr. Hall, and much appreciated.

Comment: @AerosolSP there is no reason you can't create new variables. The branch of the macro has to just be a single expression (i.e. if you create a variable and do something with it, the whole expression must be enclosed in braces): 

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=06545da95b31cb540a58a4b21af23d7b

Think about how the vec! macro works. It has to create a new vector: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.7.0/book/macros.html

Comment: That being said, using the format! macro is still a much cleaner solution. I just want to make sure you don't think that you can't create a variable in a macro.

Comment: @ObliqueMotion I think the confusion might be from the fact that you can't create a variable in a macro that you then use _outside_ of the macro.

Comment: @ObliqueMotion thanks a lot for that clarification. I thought the Rustlings course would be a bit more thorough, but I'm beginning to realize I should've gone through the book first!